# Как правильно использовать serialize() формы на клиенте и на стороне сервера?

Tags: ajax, serialize, php, codeigniter

Делаю так:

```
var formSubmit = $(element).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {formData : formSubmit, data : data },....
```

Как правильно принять на стороне сервера? чтобы можно было проверить правилами валидации Codeigniter?

Comment: зачем вообще сериализовывать что-то?

> чтобы можно было проверить правилами валидации Codeigniter?

Сомневаюсь, что валидатор волнует источник данных

Comment: Сериализация не для валидации, если вы так строго и неправильно поняли эту связь...ниже в ответе - описал проблему более четко

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я так и не понял, зачем она изначально нужна.

Comment: Чтобы в Jquery не перечислять все поля формы - их около 10. 
Суть уже не в этом. Когда передаю анг текст и вывожу в var_dump - получаю: string(42) "subject=ffff&message=gjigiun"
Если на русском:  string(42) "subject=аыаыа&message;=ыоаыаы"

Вставляется точка с запятой почему-то..и после parse_str - в массиве нет значения message

Comment: Массив на выходе от parse_str:

Array
(
    [subject] => ллллллллл
    [message;] => оииили
)

Comment: Никто не в может предположить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается, что так:

```
parse_str($this->input->post('formData'),$array);
$_POST['message'] = $array['message'];
```

Comment: Но при таком варианте - parse_str() не пропускает русский текст

Comment: var_dump $_POST показывает:
&message;=сообщение"
Почему-то вставляется ; после message